# Save output to a file per user session with NodeJS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my first NodeJS project and I would like to record onchange events to a log file per user session, so i can track different people and what they did with the application. So far my code just keeps appending to the one log file I have. I have found references to a session module that could possibly be used, but I am not sure if that is the correct route for my use case.

```
const app = require('express')();
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  var readStream = fs.createReadStream('index.html','utf8');
  readStream.pipe(res);
});

app.post('/:fieldName/:flag/:time', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('POST message received', req.params);
    if (req.params && req.params.fieldName) {
        await fs.appendFileSync('./changeLog.csv', `${req.params.fieldName},${req.params.flag},${req.params.time}`, 'utf8', "\r\n");
    }
});

https.createServer({
    pfx: fs.readFileSync('<path>'),
    passphrase: '<phrase>'
}, app).listen(3000);
```

Here is my listener function on my separate JS file.

```
let unregisterHandlerFunction = worksheet.addEventListener(tableau.TableauEventType.FilterChanged,(filterEvent) => {
  //const time = get
  let changeMessage = filterEvent.fieldName + ' filter changed on ' + getDateTimestamp()
  fieldIndicator = 'Filter'
  time = getDateTimestamp()
  const data = { change: changeMessage };
  const details = {
    method: 'POST',
  };
  fetch(`https://<url>/${filterEvent.fieldName}/${fieldIndicator}/${time}`, details).then((res) => {console.log(res);});
});
```

Comment: How do you currently tell one user apart from another user? Nothing here suggests that you do that. Also, I would suggest you don't use the `*Sync` versions of `fs` as it's blocking and can severely limit how much you can scale. The `await` is pointless.

Comment: I 'assumed' I could do that by generating an ID at the time that the events started to occur. To your point, it's definitely not recorded on my current code. I suppose I should delete this question and focus on how to address that first

Comment: Once you have the answer to that question, I imagine the problem you have in this question is quickly solved

Comment: Thank you @Evert. I will delete this question right after this last question on this subject. As far as addressing the issue of telling one user apart from the other, do you advise any specific modules or approach to do so based on what you see how my code is structured so far? I will research and try it before coming back here, but just need to be pointed towards the most suitable direction if possible. Thank you

Comment: It's a bit hard to give you a specific answer, but you will likely at least need something like `express-session`